# How to hide an element with slide effect in a specific direction with using a callback function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, callback, hide, slide

I'm using JQuery to hide an element with slide effect like this:

```
$(".teaser_container:visible").hide("slide", function() {  
  doSomething();        
});
```

This works fine, but slides the element to the left. I want to slide it to the right, but can't find any example/syntax how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide):

```
$(".teaser_container:visible").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, function(){});
```

> **direction**
>
> Type:
>       String
>
> Default:
>       "left"
>
> The direction of the effect. Can be "left", "right", "up", "down".

Comment: @Kapil: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TkHzk/. Make sure you include jQuery UI and the correct jQuery version.